# Scala TwoSum can't get Array[Int]

Tags: arrays, scala, methods, sum

can you please halp me with my solution. I write some method it  get some Array[Int], and target and find summ

```
Example:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int) : Array[Int] = {  
      val numSorted = nums.sorted
      for (i <- 0 until numSorted.length) {
        for (j <- i + 1 until numSorted.length) {
          val l = numSorted(i) + numSorted(j)
          if (l == target) {
             Array(nums.indexOf(numSorted(i)), nums.indexOf(numSorted(j)))
          }
        }
      }
    }
    val nums = Array(2, 7, 11, 15)
    val target = 9
    twoSum(nums,target)
```

my code is worked without method twoSum , but when I put it into method it get ERROR

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Array[Int]
```

Comment: Well, you are not returning anything.

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: Well, the simplest way would be to add a `return` before the `Array` and add another `return Array.empty` or something at the end of the method, depending on what you need / want to do in the case there is no match. - My advice would be to pick a course / tutorial / book that teaches you the language. BTW, this would be a declarative solution to that problem: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/d2xABS65T4iDWn0xty5V7w/3

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know. I have a  problem with understanding Scala. I'm just started. I read a books,  started courses on cursera and this task it's from leed code. I need more time for dive into the Scala. Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 3):

Well, your function isn't returning anything, as explained in the comments (but using `return` is considered a bad practice in scala, so, I would advice against that).

I also wanted to mention, that it's not a very good solution, because it is quadratic (the nested loop makes it very slow when the array is large)...
Also, it doesn't look very much like scala code I am afraid.

I would suggest something like this:

```
     def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int) = {
        val diffs = nums.map(target - _).zipWithIndex.toMap
        nums.zipWithIndex.collectFirst { 
            case (n, i) if (diffs.get(n).nonEmpty) => Array(i, diffs(n))
        }.getOrElse(Array.empty)
     }
```

First, this creates a hash map of every possible difference between the target and an array element to the index of that element.
Then it scans the array looking for the the first number that appears in the map: if the key in the map equals to the current element, then the sum of this element and the one at the index, pointed to by the mapped value equals the target.

I recommend that you try running each of these statements separately ini REPL and seeing what exactly they do.

Comment: Would it work for `nums = Array(3,2,4)` and `target = 6` ?

Comment: @Michael I don't see why not ...

Comment: I just tried it with `nums = Array(3,2,4)` and `target = 6` and get `Array(0,0)` instead of `Array(1,2)`.

Comment: @Michael (0,0) is the right answer. (If you want to add a requirement that indices must be different, just add `&& i != diffs(n)` to the guard expression).

Answer (score 1):

In Scala the last line in a function is what is returned. Typically in other languages this is `return x` where as in Scala it can just be `x` without the `return` keyword.

In your code snippet there is no return value so Scala infers the type to be `Unit` which does not match up with your return type `Array[Int]` so there is a type mismatch as reported by the compiler.

Here's your code with @Luis suggestions in comments to address the issue.

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int) : Array[Int] = {  
      val numSorted = nums.sorted
      for (i <- 0 until numSorted.length) {
        for (j <- i + 1 until numSorted.length) {
          val l = numSorted(i) + numSorted(j)
          if (l == target) {
            return Array(nums.indexOf(numSorted(i)), nums.indexOf(numSorted(j)))
          }
        }
      }
      return Array.empty
    }
```

It now type checks and runs OK.

```
scala> :load twoSum.scala
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int]
                                                                                                                              
scala> twoSum(Array(2,7,11,15), 9)
val res0: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1)
```

Comment: Wonder how you got that output. As written, this function always returns an empty array.

Comment: Ahh. Good catch. Copy/paste issue between local REPL and here. It needs the return statements.